# MySQL Join. Joining multiple rows from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `Articles`. I also have a table for `Tags`. The tags table actually has 2 separate tables as its a many-to-many relationship between Articles and Tags. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Articles (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
    title VARCHAR(255),
    author INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL -- column type may not be representative
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Tags (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(32)
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Article_Tags (
    article INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    tag INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (article) REFERENCES Articles (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (tag) REFERENCES Tags (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Now, is it possible to do a single query to return an article, and also all the tags related to that article from the Tags table in the same query?

Comment: No it's not homework. I actually posted a question on the CodeIgniter forums (I can link if you need me to) relating to a project and someone suggested doing a single query. I was asking because I wasn't sure if it's possible.

Comment: You would typically do a `select * from table1 inner join table2 on table2.table1ID = table1.id inner join table3 ON table3.id = table2.table3id` where `table2` is your link table.

Comment: I see. I need to recap on my joins have not used them for a while.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (e.g. appropriate `CREATE TABLE` statements)  is more useful than any ad-hoc table schema or english description of table columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, you typically use a `JOIN` statement to combine related records from multiple tables.

**Note that I assume that**

- `Articles` has an `ID` column
- `Article_Tags` has an `ArticleID` and `TagID` column
- `Tags` has an `ID` column

If the actual column names differ, you should replace the corresponding columns in my statement with their actual names.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT *
FROM   Articles a
       INNER JOIN Article_Tags at ON at.ArticleID = a.ID
       INNER JOIN Tags t ON t.ID = at.TagID
```

**More information about the [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) syntax**

> SQL joins are used to query data from two or more tables, based on a
>   relationship between certain columns in these tables

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [an aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine the tags if you want to get back just a single row.

Assuming that `article` has `(id, title, content)`, `tag` has `(id, name)`, and `article_tags` (the join table) has `(tag_id, article_id)`, then something like this ought to do it (obviously, not tested):

```
SELECT a.title,
       a.content,
       GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT t.name 
        ORDER BY ASC
        SEPARATOR ", "
      ) as tags
FROM article a
INNER JOIN article_tags at ON at.article_id = a.id
INNER JOIN tag t ON t.id = at.tag_id
GROUP BY a.id
```